# Vim: loop through buffer with shortcut

Tags: vim, macvim

I currently have `map << <C-^>` in my .vimrc to go back to previous buffer.  But ideally, I would like to be able to keep pressing `<<` to keep going back on the buffers.  Is there a way to map `<<` to loop through all buffers backwards and map `>>` to loop through all buffers forward?

Comment: `<<` and `>>` are precious commands that you shouldn't override.

Answer (score 2):

The commands you need to map are `bprevious` and `bnext` which are respectively buffer previous and buffer next.

```
:nnoremap << :bp<cr>
:nnoremap >> :bn<cr>
```

Comment: This is so genius, it's ridiculous. How am I just learning this now? Thank you!